# Custom Lint for Java / Android Report if we find a class call without implementing its interface

Tags: java, android, abstract-syntax-tree, lint

I am writing a custom lint detector for fun. I am going off the Big Nerd Ranches lesson on creating a [custom lint rule in Android](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-custom-lint-checks-in-android/) (should be the same for Java)

I can detect the occurrence I want. That the class constructor was called. However due to the fact we are traversing via an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) 
I am failing to detect the implementation of the callback. I am not sure how to tell Java to check the file and only report if it could not find an occurrence. In this case the interface implementation. As I only am seeing one leaf at a time.

How do I look for two occurrences, store the locations each occurrence happened and then perform my logic and report accordingly?

```
package com.bignerdranch.linette.detectors;

import com.android.annotations.NonNull;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Category;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Context;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Detector;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Implementation;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Issue;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.JavaContext;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Location;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Scope;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Severity;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.TextFormat;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.ast.AstVisitor;
import lombok.ast.Node;

/**
 * Lint check for the usage of to-do statements
 */
public class CallBackDetector extends Detector implements Detector.JavaScanner {

    private static final String FRAGMENT_MATCHER_STRING = "NoInternetDialogFragment()";
    private static final String INTERFACE_MATCHER_STRING =
            "NoInternetDialogFragment.NoInternetCallbackInterface";

    private static final Class<? extends Detector> DETECTOR_CLASS = CallBackDetector.class;
    private static final EnumSet<Scope> DETECTOR_SCOPE = Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE;

    private static final Implementation IMPLEMENTATION = new Implementation(
            DETECTOR_CLASS,
            DETECTOR_SCOPE
    );

    private static final String ISSUE_ID = "NoInternetDialogFragment";
    private static final String ISSUE_DESCRIPTION =
            "NoInternetDialogFragment Callback not detected";
    private static final String ISSUE_EXPLANATION =
            "When using NoInternetDialogFragment you must implement its' callback -- "
                    + "NoInternetCallbackInterface";
    private static final Category ISSUE_CATEGORY = Category.CORRECTNESS;
    private static final int ISSUE_PRIORITY = 10;
    private static final Severity ISSUE_SEVERITY = Severity.ERROR;

    public static final Issue ISSUE = Issue.create(
            ISSUE_ID,
            ISSUE_DESCRIPTION,
            ISSUE_EXPLANATION,
            ISSUE_CATEGORY,
            ISSUE_PRIORITY,
            ISSUE_SEVERITY,
            IMPLEMENTATION
    );

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link CallBackDetector} check
     */
    public CallBackDetector() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull File file) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends Node>> getApplicableNodeTypes() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AstVisitor createJavaVisitor(@NonNull JavaContext context) {
        String source = context.getContents();

        // Check validity of source
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(source.indexOf(INTERFACE_MATCHER_STRING) >=0){
            return null;
        }
        int index = source.indexOf(FRAGMENT_MATCHER_STRING);

        for (int i = index; i >= 0; i = source.indexOf(FRAGMENT_MATCHER_STRING, i + 1)) {
            Location location = Location.create(context.file, source, i,
                    i + FRAGMENT_MATCHER_STRING.length());
            context.report(ISSUE, location, ISSUE.getBriefDescription(TextFormat.TEXT));
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: what if class constructor will be wrapped into some factory method ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you store the references that you find as a field and report them at the end of all syntax traversal:

Inside `createJavaVisitor` do the check like you have now for the use of the constructor. Instead of reporting an issue at this point create a collection field in your `CallBackDetector` that will hold a reference to the use of the constructor. You will then end up with a list of all the constructor uses.

Now also inside `createJavaVisitor` do the check for any class implementing the interface you are searching for and add this to another field collection.

You can override the method `afterCheckProject` ([api here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.tools.lint/lint_api/r16/com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Detector.java#Detector.afterCheckProject%28com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Context%29)) in your `Detector` to know when its finished. In this method, iterate through your two collections and remove any items from both collections that are a matching pair (the constructor and the interface being implemented). Any that are left in either collection are your Lint errors, and you can add them as issues at this point.